# Rails 3 & devise_ldap_authenticatable: Authorization against Active Directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, active-directory, devise, authorization

I successfully have my Rails 3 app running with devise and devise_ldap_authenticatable to *authenticate* against the local Active Directory.

Now I want to add *authorization* capabilities in order to allow access only to AD users that belong to certain AD groups.

So to start simple, I first have looked up my own user in AD with the linux command ldapsearch. The result contained something like ...

```
(...)
memberOf: CN=my,OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=role,DC=domain,DC=com
memberOf: CN=my,OU=foo,DC=bar2,DC=role,DC=domain,DC=com
memberOf: (...)
(...)
```

Ok, now I decided, that I want to restrict access to members of `CN=my,OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=role,DC=domain,DC=com.`

So, I changed my ldap.yml to contain:

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
  group_base: ou=role,dc=domain,dc=com
  required_groups:
    - CN=my,OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=role,DC=domain,DC=com

development:
  (...)
  <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

And in addition changed my devise.rb to contain:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.ldap_logger = true
  config.ldap_create_user = true
  config.ldap_update_password = false
  config.ldap_check_group_membership = true # <-- activated this line
  config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true
  #config.ldap_ad_group_check = true <-- don't know what this is good for
```

Now, when trying to authenticate, access is denied, which I did not expect:

```
User CN=myuser,OU=org,DC=domain,DC=com is not in group: CN=my,OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=role,DC=domain,DC=com
```

Any idea, how authorization against AD is accomplished with devise_ldap_authenticatable? The documentation of this module is not yet that comprehensive when it comes to authorization.

Comment: Please answer your question below (commit a answer). This way the question remains (unnecessary open).

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Be careful of the upper case 'CN' and 'OU' in the require_attribute, otherwise it won't work. Takes me some hours...

Comment: Could you post a self-answer, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** Adding an answer on behalf of the OP ([@kwirschau](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9229308/revisions))

---

1. Change `devise.rb` to activate the attribute `ldap_check_attributes` and remove/comment out `ldap_check_group` as it does not check against the AD-specific attribute `memberOf`
2. Change `ldap.yml` and comment out `group_base` and `required_groups`. Add the required group membership to `require_attribute`.

In summary, the setup for the example in the question looks like this:

```
# devise.rb

Devise.setup do |config|
  # [ ... ]
  config.ldap_check_attributes = true
  # [ ... ]
end
```

and

```
# ldap.yml

# [ ... ]
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
  #group_base: ou=role,dc=domain,dc=com
  #required_groups:
  #  - CN=my,OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=role,DC=domain,DC=com
  require_attribute:
    memberOf: CN=my,OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=role,DC=domain,DC=com
# [ ... ]
```

Comment: Thanks. This should be put into the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

So, the answer by zekus will only work if the user is directly a member of the given group.
It will not search groups recursively. kwirschau, you were almost there with your initial configuration. You stated:

```
"#config.ldap_ad_group_check = true <-- don't know what this is good for"
```

When that flag is set, the ldap query will search nested groups by using a filter with the LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN rule, which searches the user's groups recursively.

Thus, in your devise.rb, set:

```
  config.ldap_check_group_membership = true
  config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true
  config.ldap_ad_group_check = true
```

Set your authorization group in your ldap.yml

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
  group_base: ou=role,dc=domain,dc=com
  required_groups:
    - CN=my,OU=foo,DC=bar,DC=role,DC=domain,DC=com
```

Additionally, in your code, if you want to check a user against another group, don't use "memberOf", as this will not search nested groups. Instead, use:

```
ldap_connect = Devise::LdapAdapter.ldap_connect(username)
ldap_connect.in_group?(group_name)
```